# How to show records for a particular month

Tags: ms-access

[image]

Show the Sales, Profit and ShipDate fields (only) of any records from the month of January (any year) where Region and Province are both Ontario.

Comment: What datatype is ShipDate?

Answer (score 1):

....... AND Month(Shipdate) = 1

Answer (score 0):

Does your shipdate in invoice table contain a date or a month only. If it's a date then you need to define an expression (a new field in your query as expression `Month (shipdate)` and then put your WHERE criteria January in newly defined expression. Hope this helps.